# Ionic 4 : why page generate command creates module file and there is no cli command for generate only modules for better Structure of project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-cli, ionic4, ionic-cli

Ionic 4 : why every page generate command creates module file and there is no cli command for generate only modules for better abstraction.

> I know the difference between modules and components. modules used for
>   lazy loading so it can load only whenever it requested only, But my
>   question is does it required to generate module for every single page?

Ionic 4 CLI doesn't provide generate commands for custom modules like angular does.

what if i do have some static information pages which doesn't required lazy loading (**separate modules for every page**) for these scenario which one is the best way (for performance of the application).

-> **To create a custom module manually and create components of pages** 
OR
-> **Use ionic4 cli and use generate page command**

Comment: you can use angular cli to generate modules 'ng g module yourModule' also as I understand you should follow [angular conventions](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)  during structure your app as ionic now is  not based on angular as was in older versions

Comment: Thanks for your time @karimAhmed.
My question is do we need to use module for every mobile page? or with we can use just component which one is best for mobile browser

Comment: I think it'll give you a better performance when each page is a lazy-loaded module.  please read [this blog](https://blog.ionicframework.com/how-to-lazy-load-in-ionic-angular/)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the time @KarimAhmed